# Customize Refactoring for Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, refactoring, automated-refactoring

This is a small quality of life issue, but I'm curious if there is a solution.

I'm working with a python file in visual studio code. I'm using the "Extract Method" feature to do some refactoring. When I do so, VS Code places the new method below the method from which I'm extracting it. I would like it to place it above instead.

I've searched what I could think of in VS Code's settings ("refactor" "extract method")
I've done some googling and searching on stack overflow specifically but haven't found anything like this.

Does anyone know of a way to modify this behavior?

Comment: This function is not currently supported. To request it, open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python .

Comment: By the way, the Extract Method will overwrite the original method. If the last run method is above on the definition, it will report an error.